# Changing the checkout flow in spree-0.10.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I need a checkout process devoid of a delivery and payment step 
(working on a store which accept cash on delivery so I need only the 
address step.) 
I am using [Spree 0.10.2](http://spreecommerce.com/)

Things I have tried: 
In the `site_extension.rb` added the following state machine

```
Checkout.state_machines[:state] = StateMachine::Machine.new(Checkout, :initial => 'address') do 
      after_transition :to => 'complete', :do => :complete_order 
      before_transition :to => 'complete', :do => :process_payment 
      event :next do 
        transition :to => 'complete', :from => 'address' 
      end 
    end
```

The unwanted steps are removed (at least visually) but when I submit 
the address it throws up the following error.

> IndexError in
>   CheckoutsController#update 
>       "payment" is an invalid name

Looking at the trace and couple of similar errors later, I decide to 
blindly override two methods from checkouts_controller.rb in 
site_extension.rb to do nothing (since they deal with payment I 
presume)

```
 def clear_payments_if_in_payment_state 
 end

 def object_params 
 end
```

Doing this throws validation errors on all the fields of delivery and 
billing address. 
I vaguely have a notion that I need to override a couple of methods 
from checkouts_controller.rb. If this notion is right then what are 
those methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to :

1) Remove the paymenttransition and delivery state transition step.

2) Also overriding the payment_required method .

3) These steps need to be in order_decorator.rb under app/models/spree directory.

```
checkout_flow do
    go_to_state :address
   # go_to_state :payment
    go_to_state :complete
    remove_transition :from => :delivery, :to => :confirm
    remove_transition :from => :delivery, :to => :confirm
    remove_transition :from => :payment, :to => :confirm
  end
  #Spree::Order.state_machine.before_transition :to => :payment, :do => :set_order

  def set_order
    self.create_proposed_shipments
  end
  def require_email
    return false
  end
  def payment_required?
    false
  end
```

I have tested this on spree 2-0-stable with rails 3.2.14.

Comment: Though this is for another version than what I asked for, I have accepted the answer because it should work for the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I can't really help you: Customizing the checkout process with Spree 0.10.2 is kind of a nightmare. 
But I would recommend to switch to a more recent version of Spree, like the **1.3-stable**.
If you switched to that one, it would be as easy as creating an `order_decorator.rb` file in `your_app_folder/app/models/spree` with the following code:

```
Spree::Order.class_eval do
  remove_checkout_step :delivery 
  remove_checkout_step :payment
end
```